# "Error: Can't open display: :0" - running GUI apps as another user

Tags: xorg, openbsd

Installed OpenBSD with all the sets and using the default FVWM2.

I log in to FVWM2, open xterm:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
$
```

And "su -" to root and create a normal user:

```
useradd -m TESTUSER
```

ok! Now I:

```
# su - TESTUSER
$ export DISPLAY=":0" 
$ xcalc               
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: :0
$
```

If I try (with the normal user with I logged in to FVWM2):

```
$ xhost +
```

Then it works (the "TESTUSER" can launch xcalc)! But I don't want to allow any to connect to my X server. Only a given local user. But I cannot add the local user:

```
$ xhost +local:TESTUSER    
non-network local connections being added to access control list
$ xhost              
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
LOCAL:
$
```

With the "LOCAL:" I think I enable all the local users, which is BAD.

**Q:** How to only enable the given local useR?

Comment: does `export DISPLAY=:0.0` change anything?

Comment: updated question, found something

Comment: Have a look at `xauth` and `.Xauthority`. Users must be authenticated (MIT magic cookie) before being able to use the X server. Much safer than `xhost`.

Comment: wow, thanks, but why is it safer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ xhost +si:localuser:TESTUSER
```

worked with the user that started the X (FVWM2)